# Which number should I use for In-between group analysis by using Fisher's exact test?

Tags: r, excel, spss

I have to find out if the baseline demographics have statistically significant difference between two groups. The project is about two groups of students, one intervention group and one control group. The goal is to find out if the students in the intervention group that pass the test will be significantly more than that in the control group. I need to perform an in-between group analysis to see if the gender is a factor affecting the result. I would like to know which number should I put in to the 2X2 table test? Which of the following should I use?

```
                  Intervention group      Control Group
Passing Male:           28                     23
Passing Female:         41                     30

           Intervention group    Control Group
Male     :           30               27
Female   :           42               33
```

I am wondering if sex is affecting the the passing rate between each group. I guess it is called "between group differences" at baseline? For examples, I want to know if male students are more likely to pass the test, if it is, then it may affect the results as the two groups do not have the same proportion of male to female students in each of the two groups? I want to know if sex is a covariate affecting the passing rate.

Comment: You also need to present either the total group sizes or the number not passing. (Or clarify that the numbers is the second table were the numbers tested. And say why you wouldn't use a chi-squared analysis which could handle the 2x2x2 structure better than a `fisher.test`)

Answer (score 1):

The Fisher Exact Test is not set up to handle covariates. There are exact tests that do handle covariates, but they require additional packages in R. I would set the data up like this:

```
> res2
  Pass Tot    Sex Grp
1   28  30   Male Int
2   41  42 Female Int
3   23  27   Male Ctl
4   30  33 Female Ctl
```

Then run two models (admittedly not using exact tests): one with both Sex and Grp and another with Grp removed. Clearly these two groups are not matched, so McNemar's test is not used either, although it could be argued that the selection methods for grouping were not described very well, if at all. Clearly there is nothing approaching a significant difference using logistic regression:

```
glm( cbind(Pass, Tot-Pass) ~ Sex + Grp, data=res2, family="binomial")
#-----------
Call:  glm(formula = cbind(Pass, Tot - Pass) ~ Sex + Grp, family = "binomial", 
    data = res2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      SexMale       GrpInt  
     2.3946      -0.7147       1.0965  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  1 Residual
Null Deviance:      3.922 
Residual Deviance: 0.1249   AIC: 16.65
#----------------

glm( cbind(Pass, Tot-Pass) ~ Sex , data=res2, family="binomial")
#------------
Call:  glm(formula = cbind(Pass, Tot - Pass) ~ Sex, family = "binomial", 
    data = res2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      SexMale  
     2.8764      -0.7363  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  2 Residual
Null Deviance:      3.922 
Residual Deviance: 2.688    AIC: 17.21
#------
```

Looking at the actual numbers you can see why random variation could easily explain differences of just a few students one or two groups. Comparing the deviance of two models, which is what I am implicitly doing, is a likelihood ratio test. The difference between that approach and an exact test would be expected to be very slight when the cell sizes all exceed 5. Furthermore the calculation of an exact test with this set of values would be prohibitive. I seem to remember that the R `fisher.test` may allow a more relaxed accommodation of data than just 2x2, but when the cell counts are this large the function would default to approximate methods anyway.

Comment: Using the `cbind` function with `glm` logistic regression , the values should be successes and failures, not successes and total.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading the `?glm` material incorrectly. Better to look at `?esoph`. Code and output revised accordingly.